# Access `by` variable from within `j` in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

If I have a `data.table` and I'm doing some function call in the `j`, do I have access to the current value of the `by` variable?

```
library(data.table)
d <- data.table(x=1:10, y=c('a', 'b'))

myfun <- function(DT) {
  print (DT$y)
}


d[, myfun(.SD), by=y]
```

For more context, I am passing a second argument (another `data.table`) to `myfun` and want to subset that based on the current value of `y`.  It could be done with a dummy variable, but that seems yucky...

Comment: Can you use `.GRP`? `d[, .GRP, by=y]`

Comment: @Roland Hmm, I didn't know about `.GRP` but it is just an index correct? I could, but then I'm starting to add extra subsetting.

Comment: It should be relatively easy to turn the corresponding column in your other data.table into an integer. However, maybe there is a better approach to your real problem. You'd need to show it.

Comment: @Roland To be sure.  I have a few other options for my real code.  But, I was mostly interested for future reference and curiosity.  E.g. a progress update on long running code that prints the current `by` variable when it starts or something...

Comment: I can think of two ways: 1) Add a second argument to your function and pass `y`- `my.fun(.SD, y)`. Remember that grouping variables will be of length 1 (as of now, there's an issue somewhere yet to be fixed). 2) Use `.SDcols` and add `y` as well to it, then `.SD` will contain the `y` column as well Ex: `d[, my.fun(.SD), by=y, .SDcols=1:2]`

Comment: @Arun option 1 was what I was looking for more or less.  Feel free to make it an answer.  I was really hoping that the grouping variable would be passed in as an attribute on `.SD` or something like that...

Comment: @Justin, it just hasn't come up is all I'd think. Feel free to file a FR if you think that might be a nice thing to have.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `.BY` - which is a list of `by` variables:

```
d <- data.table(x=1:10, y=c('a', 'b'))
d[, .BY[[1]], by = y]  # [[1]] to access the first by variable, which is y
                       # if you had by = list(x, y) you'd do .BY[[2]] to access y
#   y V1
#1: a  a
#2: b  b
```

Additionally the list is named, so you can also access it by name:

```
d[, .BY$y, by = y]
```

Comment: that's nice, but you'll have to pass it explicitly if you write a function, right?