# Operations on a calculated .BY in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, roc

As an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733151/access-by-variable-from-within-j-in-data-table), I'd like to run calculations that include a `.BY` variable that is itself the product of a calculation.  The questions I've reviewed use a key that merely accesses, but does not transform or aggregate, an existing value.

In this example, I'm trying to produce a ROC for a binary classifier with a function that exploits `data.table` (because ROC calculations in existing packages are quite slow).  In this case, the `.BY` variable is the cutpoint, and the calculations are the true positive and false positive rates for a probability estimate at that cutpoint.

I am able to do this with an intermediate `data.table`, but I am looking for a more efficient solution.  This works:

```
# dummy example
library(data.table)
dt <- setDT(get(data(GermanCredit, package='caret'))
            )[, `:=`(y = as.integer(Class=='Bad'),
                     Class = NULL)]
model <- glm(y ~ ., family='binomial', data=dt)
dt[,y_est := predict(model, type='response')]

#--- Generate ROC with specified # of cutpoints  ---
# level of resolution of ROC curve -- up to uniqueN(y_est)
res <- 5 

# vector of cutpoints (thresholds for y_est)
cuts <- dt[,.( thresh=quantile(y_est, probs=0:res/res) )]

# at y_est >= each threshold, how many true positive and false positives?
roc <-  cuts[, .( tpr = dt[y_est>=.BY[[1]],sum(y==1)]/dt[,sum(y==1)],
                  fpr = dt[y_est>=.BY[[1]],sum(y==0)]/dt[,sum(y==0)]
                 ), by=thresh]

plot(tpr~fpr,data=roc,type='s') # looks right
```

[image]

But this doesn't work:

```
# this doesn't work, and doesn't have access to the total positives & negatives
dt[, .(tp=sum( (y_est>=.BY[[1]]) & (y==1)  ),
       fp=sum( (y_est>=.BY[[1]]) & (y==0)  ) ),
   keyby=.(thresh= quantile(y_est, probs=0:res/res) )]
# Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , .(tp = sum((y_est >= .BY[[1]]) & (y == 1)),  : 
#   The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (6).
#   Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (1000).
```

Is there an idiomatically data.table (or at least more efficient) way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use non-equi joins:

```
dt[.(thresh = quantile(y_est, probs=0:res/res)), on = .(y_est >= thresh),
   .(fp = sum(y == 0), tp = sum(y == 1)), by = .EACHI][,
   lapply(.SD, function(x) x/x[1]), .SDcols = -"y_est"]
#           fp          tp
#1: 1.00000000 1.000000000
#2: 0.72714286 0.970000000
#3: 0.46857143 0.906666667
#4: 0.24142857 0.770000000
#5: 0.08142857 0.476666667
#6: 0.00000000 0.003333333
```

Comment: This is magically wonderful, thank you.  I understand lines 2 & 3 -- that `x/x[1]` trick is clever.  But line 1: I am trying to grok the non-equi join, which is apparently a new-ish feature (v1.9.8).  Can you help me understand what is going on with `i` in line 1?  There is no `Y` as in `X[Y]` because it's a self-join?

Comment: The dot there is equivalent to typing `data.table`, so it's as if I wrote `dt[cuts,...`